# Making a page content slider animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, slider

[image]

I'd like to make a two page slider to move through the content. Is it possible to make a CSS code to do the animation like in this [example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#&panel1-1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eWv57/23/)**

**css**

```
body {
    font:normal 1.25em/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

.demo-wrapper {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}

/**
 * Slider CSS
 */
.slider {
    /* For no JS situations */
    overflow: auto;
}
.slider > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    /* Force list items onto a single line and remove white space */
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;

    /* Only WebKit requires prefix */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slider > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.slider .next,
.slider .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1em;
    padding: .5em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider .next {
    right: 0;
}
.slider .prev {
    left: 0;
}

.slider .prev.is-disabled,
.slider .next.is-disabled {
    opacity: .25;
}

/* Full width variation */
.slider--fit li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/)**

Comment: Yes something like 'demo' but I'd like some transition, like in my example. When clicking next it transites in the opposite direction for few pixels, then goes on to the next page.